# how to sum specific intervals of row in r?

Tags: r, sum, rows

I have x,y data. I want to sum y values of each row according to certain values of x-axis. lets say from 2.3 to 4.4 in R.
How do I sum with from-to condition?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... then edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42888655/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(df$y[df$x > 2.3 & df$x < 4.4])
```